# Are questions about seeking for music that is used for specific purpose on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

If my question is "has there been any music that is used for the purpose of _______?", would it be on-topic?

Reading [What topics can I ask about here?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I'm not sure if it's on-topic or not. On one hand, probably it falls to the category of

> Information about music memorabilia and the collection of it (e.g. “How rare is X?”)

On the other hand, it can be perceived as

> Recommendations of what to listen to

I also see that this question may be subjective. However, it seems to be a good subjective one, as explained in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/):

[image]

What do you think? Below is my draft.

---

> I am making a video about a topic involves challenging some false beliefs and misunderstandings, correcting them, and inviting the viewers to analyze and verify the information themselves. The video is not long (~15 minutes), but the problem is I need the viewers to feel relax and comfortable and interested in the topic, since they may not be interested in the topic, and if they do, they will probably be emotional and defensive.
>
> There are several YouTube channels that introduce abstract concepts and require the viewers to spend time analyzing the information. One notable example that comes to my mind is [3Blue1Brown](https://www.3blue1brown.com/), whose music is [here](https://vincerubinetti.bandcamp.com/album/the-music-of-3blue1brown). However, I still feel that the music doesn't really fit.
>
> I have a feeling that classical music can solve this, because it is the most complex form of music. Has there been any music that is used for this purpose?
>
> <sup>Some relevant concepts: [Socratic questioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_questioning), [perspective-taking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective-taking), [assume good faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presumption_of_innocence), [frame challenge](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2511/86), [cognitive dissonance](https://www.simplypsychology.org/cognitive-dissonance.html)</sup>

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, what would be **off-topic** is a question that:

1. Call for **opinions** rather than facts. You can't ask a vague question and expect people throwing random personal ideas so you can find what answer fits you the best.
2. Are **too broad** and without specific boundaries, so it's never ending.

If you ask *"has there been any music that is used for the purpose of _______?"* and I give you an example, and someone else comes and gives another example, we are both right. Keep in mind that the point of Stack Exchange is to accept answers so you question needs to be specific about what kind of answers you are expecting, with boundaries and what kind of facts (proofs) you are looking after.

I also notice that the answer of your question is almost 100% "Yes" because it is almost impossible to [prove the inexistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence_of_absence) of something. With the thousands of (bad) videos that are produced everyday, you can be sure that any kind of (bad) music has been (badly) used to accompany any kind of video purpose.

A decent set of boundaries that we often use here is a "success metric" that will narrow the sea of potential answers. It can be charts, number of views/likes.

---

About your draft, I see your **purpose** is to find music to accompany a video that helps:

> the viewers to feel relax and comfortable and interested in the topic, since they may not be interested in the topic, and if they do, they will probably be emotional and defensive.

What would be your metric to see if it worked? What are the criteria? Apparently, having a decent number of viewers and likes like in *3Blue1Brown* videos is not a satisfying metric for you?

Then when you say:

> However, I still feel that the music doesn't really fit.

In what do you think it doesn't fit? Is it just *opinion*? If you want advice and suggestion, maybe you should first specify what you don't like.

Finally:

> I have a feeling that classical music can solve this, because it is the most complex form of music.

My argued opinion is that complex music doesn't fit well with videos where people need to stay focus. The complexity of the music will attract the brain to the music and distract it from the actual content of the video. Especially in high quality classical music where dynamic range is high, variating instruments, variating rhythm patterns etc. And also, if the music is famous, it will also distract people because they will react to a known song.